# groupby of a groupby to select values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows:

```
marker    date         value       identifier

EA    2007-01-01      0.33            55
EA    2007-01-01      0.73            56
EA    2007-01-01      0.51            57
EA    2007-02-01      0.13            55
EA    2007-02-01      0.23            57
EA    2007-03-01      0.82            55
EA    2007-03-01      0.88            56
EB    2007-01-01      0.13            45
EB    2007-01-01      0.74            46
EB    2007-01-01      0.56            47
EB    2007-02-01      0.93            45
EB    2007-02-01      0.23            47
EB    2007-03-01      0.82            45
EB    2007-03-01      0.38            46
EB    2007-03-01      0.19            47
```

Now I want to do a selection on this data frame by value, so I use

```
df.groupby(marker).get_group('EA')
```

But I also want to get the mean of the value, and notice that I have a duplicated date index, so now I have to do *two* groupbys because the index is different, leading to

```
df.groupby(marker).get_group('EA').groupby(df.groupby(marker).get_group('EA').index.date).mean()['value'].plot()
```

what clearly is not really legible. How can I accomplish this without creating a intermediary variable?

Comment: it's unclear what you're trying to achieve here, are you wanting to groupby marker and date? but it seems you index is also a date but that is not what your df is showing

Comment: The index is actually the date, it's just SO formatting. Yes, I want to group by marker and date, and it seems that ['marker', df.index.date ] doesn't cut it, and without having to do a group by inside a group by just because of the difference in index sizes.

Comment: So why not do `df[df['marker'] == 'EA'].groupby(df.index.date).mean()['value'].plot()`?

Comment: When I try to do this I get AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, for the reason you wrote above in your comment about the `AssertionError`. Pandas expects to do the (second) `groupby`  according to some sequence which has exactly the same length as the `DataFrame` getting grouped. If you're unwilling to first create a `DataFrame` describing the `EA` values, you're basically stuck with creating it again on the fly.

Not only is that less legible, it is unnecessarily expensive. Speaking of which, I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
eas = df[df.marker == 'EA']
eas.value.groupby(eas.date).mean().plot();
```

Doing a `groupby` and retaining a single group is a very expensive way of just filtering according to the key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this clarify what I was thinking. I agree that it can be expensive computationally wise, but would the two groupbys would use less memory?

Comment: Thanks. The memory conservation is an interesting point, but I'm afraid it requires deeper knowledge of the implementation of pandas than I have. In any case, regardless of whether you do it through filtering or groupby, I strongly suggest you use the intermediate object as above.